# Get result from multidimensional array without duplicate results in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, and would like to get all the values like this  [*][place],
without duplicate results.
The output should be looking like this :

> Sønderjylland
>   Nordjylland
>   Sjælland

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [place] => Sønderjylland
                [active] => Lagerarbejde
                [num] => 123
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [place] => Nordjylland
                [active] => Tømrer
                [num] => 124
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [place] => Sønderjylland
                [active] => Klejnsmed
                [num] => 125
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [place] => Sjælland
                [active] => Elektriker
                [num] => 126
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `array_column`, `array_unique`, `array_filter`, `implode` together.

```
echo implode(' ', array_filter(array_unique(array_column($yourArray, 'place'))));
```

`array_column` is supported for **(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)**

If you are using older versions then a loop would help.

Comment: Thank you very mauch, it is work well, how can I delete duplicate results?

Comment: The last function called shouldn't be `array_column`?

Comment: Ahh... Missed that.. Updated. Thanks!!

Comment: [Provides functionality for array_column() to projects using PHP earlier than version 5.5.](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column)